# Django model ForeignKey with subset of data

Tags: django

Is it possible to define a foreign key or OneToOne relation   in django model with only subset of data?

For example :

I have 2 models.

```
 @with_author  
    class Product(models.Model):
        GTIN = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

        UOM = models.OneToOneField(MaterialUOM)
        defaultPrice =  MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
```

and

```
 @with_author  
    class UOM(models.Model):
        uomname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

so I want in my Product model only to allow UOM values that have same material value as in product.

Is it possible on model level or any other place and  not to display non relevant values in the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce this constraint by adding some validation to the model's [`clean()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects). Something like:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Product(models.Model):
    GTIN = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    UOM = models.OneToOneField(MaterialUOM)
    defaultPrice =  MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')

    def clean(self):
        if not self.material == self.UOM.material:
            # This will cause the model not to be saved and report an error
            raise ValidationError('Material does not match UOM material')
```

If you are using a `ModelForm` to handle edits to your models, then `clean()` will be called automatically as part of the form validation. If you are modifying models directly in your code, then you need to call it yourself before saving the model. The documentation explains this in detail.

If you want to be doubly sure, you can also [override the `save()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.material == self.UOM.material:
        return # Model is not saved
    super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This will not report any errors - it will just not save the model. Hence you should also use the `clean()` method above.

Comment: `clean()` method will only be callled when the Model is being saved using `ModelForm` and not otherwise. I think overriding `save` method is better for covering other cases. And as far as the errors are concerned you could raise a custom one for this.

Comment: It is not working I cant add clean on form level since I have no material in my form even I have it in the model. And when I add clean in the model I am getting error Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
Exception Value: 
Product has no material.

Comment: even if I override the  save level my dropdown will still show all the values.

Comment: In response to your first comment: "I have no material in my form even I have it in the model" - then there is something wrong with how you are defining the form. Regarding the second comment: well yes, Django cannot know what `UOM` you are going to choose for the product and magically filter the list of `Material`s for you. You will need some client-side Javascript to do that kind of dynamic filtering.